# Google Analytics in Android app. Restrict only with Wi-Fi to save mobile data

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics in android app. I wanted GA only to send tracking when WiFi is available. This could be easily done by checking the Wi-Fi status. But I want GA to cache the events/screens when no Wi-Fi is available and send it later when Wi-Fi available.

I found in document the cache is only written when no internet is available, so what I want to ask is; is there a way to force GA cache the tracking even when mobile data is available, and no Wi-Fi? And send the cached screens and events when Wi-Fi is back online, not via mobile data.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I learned is its impossible to restrict sending GA only over Wi-Fi